# Posting data in raw format to PHP file and getting response

Tags: java, php, android, post

I am making an android application where I need to send some data collected from a data to server php file using post data and get the echoed text from the php file and display it. I have the post variables in this format -> "name=xyz&home=xyz" and so on. I am using the following class to post, but the php file on the server does not get the post vars. Can someone please tell me whats wrong or any other ways to do what I am trying to do?

```
package xxx.xxx.xxx;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class NetUtil {
    public static String UrlToString(String targetURL, String urlParameters)
      {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;  
        try {
          //Create connection
          url = new URL(targetURL);
          connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
          connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
          connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
               "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

          connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + 
                   Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
          connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  

          connection.setUseCaches (false);
          connection.setDoInput(true);
          connection.setDoOutput(true);

          //Send request
          DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                      connection.getOutputStream ());
          wr.write(urlParameters.getBytes("UTF-8"));
          wr.flush ();
          //Get Response    
          InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
          String line;
          StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
          while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
          }
          rd.close();
          return response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {

          e.printStackTrace();
          return null;

        } finally {

          if(connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect(); 
          }
        }
      }

}
```

I get a response from php file, but the php file does not get the post data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example looks okay to me for a beginner. Only the following springs out:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + 
    Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
```

and

```
wr.write(urlParameters.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

In the first you're converting chars to bytes using platform default encoding. The resulting length is not necessarily the same as when using UTF-8 encoding to convert chars to bytes as you did when writing the request body. So the chance exist that the `Content-Length` header is off from the *actual* content length. To fix this, you should be using the same charset on the both calls.

But I believe that PHP isn't really *that* strict when parsing the request body so that you would get nothing in the PHP end. Probably the `urlParameters` is not in proper format. Are they really URL-encoded?

Anyway, did you try it with Android's builtin HttpClient API? It should be as simple as follows:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(targetURL);
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "xyz"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("home", "xyz"));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
InputStream input = response.getEntity().getContent();
// ...
```

If that doesn't work as well, then the mistake is likely in the PHP side.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can see whats wrong with the above code. And about the HttpClient API, i have the data collected in a get data format like "name=xyz&phone=abc&number=123" , is there a way to use that format with the httpclient api or change that format to namevalue pair. And the above HttpClient API will post the data, but how do i get the reply from the php file as a string ? Thanks again :D

Comment: Just collect them differently. Using a `Map<String, String>` is the most straightforward choice. Pass it as method argument and then loop over it, adding a new `BasicNameValuePair` to the list everytime. As to reading the response body, just read the `input` which I already prepared for you in the code example.

Comment: Ok, that makes it clear :) Thanks for your help. I will try and reply if i get into some problem :D

Comment: @BalusC I got everything else, but how do i make a Map<String, String>  thing and pass it to the new method? I am totally new to android and java, so can you please give me a example code if possible. Thanks :D

Comment: Does it work or not? I don't understand the "I got everything else" part. As to the map, just read the [map tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) or ask a new question.

Comment: It works, but i am not being able to create a List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); object , add pair values to it and pass it to the method.

Comment: That's a different problem. The concrete problem as described in the current question has been solved. Please press `Ask Question` button in top if you can't figure it out after reading the basic collections/map tutorial. We'll help you further with this then.